# How to populate data in selectBox as current item selected by default from mysql database in angular JS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

HI  i am new to angular Basically  i have successfully populated data from database in select box but now i want  to do is to populate the current data item as a default value in selectbox from mysql database in angular js using php i am getting the data in json array .. any help would be appreciated

Here is my HTML: iwant to target **ORDER** SELECTBOX

```html
 <table ng-table="table.tableParams5" class="table table-bordered table-striped table_feature">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
     
            <th>S.No</th> 
            <th>Name</th> 
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Status</th>
           <th>SEO</th>
         <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
           
           <td data-title="'pkCategoryId'" >{{user.pkCategoryId}}</td>
           <td data-title="'Name'" >{{user.Name}}</td>
          <!--  <td data-title="'Order'">{{user.Order}}</td> -->
            <td> <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="rec.orders"  name="Order">
                         <option ng-repeat="orders in order"  value="{{orders.Order}}">{{orders.Order}}</option>
                              </select> </td>
           <td data-title="'Status'">{{user.category_outlet.Status}}</td>   
           <td></td>           
           <td>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" title="Edit" ui-sref="app.editmanage_category({id:user.pkFeatureTypeId})" >
                <em class="fa fa-pencil"></em>
            </button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" title="Delete" ng-click="delete(user.pkFeatureTypeId);">
                <em class="fa fa-trash"></em>
            </button>           
          </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is my JS

```js
$scope.order = []; 
 $resource('api/AdminArea/category/get_record').get(function(data){  
  $scope.order = data.result;
 });
```

Comment: use ngOptions directive and set ng-model to selected value https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: you have to post your angualr app.js here so we will be able to help you

Comment: thanx for the reply let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok you can do it like this

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="rec.orders"  name="Order">
    <option ng-repeat="item in order" 
            value="{{item.Order}}"
            ng-selected="{{item.Order == YOUR_VALUE}}"
           >
         {{item.Order}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Note:**

if your your saved value located in php then use `<?php echo $YOUR_VALUE; ?>` instead `YOUR_VALUE` in above code

if it located at AngularJs part then passit it to $scope then write there `item.Order == passed_js_value`

Comment: where your current item information is stored ? after page initial load from where you get it ?

Comment: Thanx it really hepled :)

Comment: actually i was confused . i just compared item.order==user.data